# jQuery onClick on working in div bound by KnockoutJS

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Quick question which is more for interest really.

I have a div which uses Knockout JS to bind a bunch of data after an AJAX request.

```
<div data-bind="with: user" id="ActionWindow">
...Stuff...
</div>
```

It all works fine.

But if I then want to use jQuery onCLick or onChange events I can't do it like this:

```
<div data-bind="with: user" id="ActionWindow">
<a class="NewGroupLink">Add New Group</a>
...Stuff...
</div>
<script>
$('.NewGroupLink').click(function () {
    alert('bob');
});
</script>
```

The event just doesn't fire.

I could put an onClick="" in the "a" and I expect that would work but why doesn't this work?

Incidently the above code works fine if the link is outside of the div.

Can anyone tell me why? And if there is a way to get the jQuery code to work?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your HTML code is within a conditional `if` of `ifnot` in knockout? Because of the way they work (they do not actually insert the contained DOM nodes unless they evaluate to `true`), the hyperlink actually might not be in the document when you're trying to hook the event.

If that is the case, my suggestion would be to use the following code to hook your event handler:

```
$('body').on('click', '.NewGroupLink', function() {
    ... 
});
```

This way, the event is actually attached to the document's body, but the handler's code only executes on the condition that the event occurs over an element with the CSS class `NewGroupLink`.

If your page is large, the code could be more precise/better performing if you use a different element (instead of `body`) that is closer to the actual link, yet still an ancestor.

Comment: Hi. That worked but I'm not sure I understand why. I don't have any conditional statements. The page is bound when a button is pressed .... ah! I have just answered my own question. All of the textboxes are bound only IF there is data. this.selectedItem = data ? data.JobTitleNum : ""; for example.

So despite my link having no data-bind tag it still wont render on the Dom. Is that right?

Comment: I believe you are correct, as the `with` binding behaves like `if`/`ifnot`.
From the documentation: *The with binding will dynamically add or remove descendant elements depending on whether the associated value is null/undefined or not*
So if `user` is undefined/null when you attempt to hook the event, the button will not be on the page so `$('.NewGroupLink').length` will be 0, and not hook the event handler to anything.

Answer (score 2):

If your target element is being created from the data you are retrieving from the ajax call, then you need to use a delegate to target the click handler (the click handler only works for elements that are present in the DOM at the time that the handler is initially run.

```
$("#ActionWindow").on( "click", ".NewGroupLink", function() {
    alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all it is a bad practice to use jquery events with knockout. KO has own events so if you want to add click handler just and handler function to your view model and add click binding to the html element:

```
<a class="NewGroupLink" data-bind="click: onClickHandler">Add New Group</a>
```

You code does not work because query code is executed before content of div is rendered. So when it is called link does not exist. This happened due to the `with` binding, it waits until `ko.applyBindings` is called and if user is not null it renders div.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `on` ([see jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/on/))

```
<div data-bind="with: user" id="ActionWindow">
<a href="#" class="NewGroupLink">Add New Group</a>
...Stuff...
</div>
<script>
$('.NewGroupLink').on('click', function () {
    alert('bob');
});
</script>
```